# Python pandas группировка части датафрейма по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сгруппировать в DataFrame в кварталы только те данные, в которых представлены все три месяца квартала?

```
     Контрагенты    Период    Год
0     Компания      Март  2022г
1     Компания    Апрель  2022г
2     Компания       Май  2022г
3     Компания      Июнь  2022г
4     Компания      Июль  2022г
5     Компания    Август  2022г
6     Компания  Сентябрь  2022г
7     Компания   Октябрь  2022г
8     Компания    Ноябрь  2022г
9     Компания   Декабрь  2022г
10    Компания      Март  2020г
11    Компания    Апрель  2020г
12    Компания      Июнь  2020г
13    Компания      Июль  2020г
14    Компания    Август  2020г
15    Компания  Сентябрь  2020г
16    Компания    Ноябрь  2020г
17    Компания   Декабрь  2020г
```

Comment: Приведите таблицы в порядок, пожалуйста.

Comment: Как пытались решить сами?

Comment: @Алексей Р Объединение столбцов период и год, затем df.groupby(замена всех Март, Апрель и т.д. на 1,2,3,4 ).count() > 2 выдало True на всех объектах, группировка которых была больше двух (значит, были все 3 месяца квартала). Дальше не могу додуматься как это применить. Кстати, спасибо, что подправили таблицу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом у вас логика правильная. Потом нужно из тех групп, где три строки, оставить одну строку и название месяца заменить на название квартала. Я сделал через apply и функцию. Если потребуется агрегировать какие-то числовые данные (сумма по кварталу, например), это также можно сделать в этой функции.

```
def fun(x):
    if x.shape[0] < 3:
        return x
    s = x.head(1)
    s.at[s.index[0], 'Период'] = f"{q[s.at[s.index[0], 'Период']]} кв."
    return s


df = pd.DataFrame({'Контрагенты': ['Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания'],
                   'Период': ['Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
                   'Год': ['2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г']})
q = {'Январь': 1, 'Февраль': 1, 'Март': 1, 'Апрель': 2, 'Май': 2, 'Июнь': 2, 'Июль': 3, 'Август': 3, 'Сентябрь': 3, 'Октябрь': 4, 'Ноябрь': 4, 'Декабрь': 4}
df = df.groupby([df['Период'].replace(q), 'Год'], as_index=False, sort=False).apply(fun).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

```
  Контрагенты   Период    Год
0    Компания     Март  2022г
1    Компания    2 кв.  2022г
2    Компания    3 кв.  2022г
3    Компания    4 кв.  2022г
4    Компания     Март  2020г
5    Компания   Апрель  2020г
6    Компания     Июнь  2020г
7    Компания    3 кв.  2020г
8    Компания   Ноябрь  2020г
9    Компания  Декабрь  2020г
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Пойду читать про shape и at.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('ru_RU.UTF-8'))
df ["Date"] = pd.to_datetime("1-"+pd.to_datetime(df['Период'], format='%B')
                             .dt.month.astype(str)+"-"+df["Год"].str[:-1], dayfirst=True)

res = pd.DataFrame()
for i,g in df.groupby([df["Date"].dt.year, df["Date"].dt.quarter]):    
    if len(g)==3:
        g["Период"] = g["Date"].dt.quarter.astype(str)+" Квартал"
        res = pd.concat([res, g.head(1).drop(columns=["Date"])])
    else:
        res = pd.concat([res, g.drop(columns=["Date"])])
```

res:

```
   Контрагенты     Период    Год
10    Компания       Март  2020г
11    Компания     Апрель  2020г
12    Компания       Июнь  2020г
13    Компания  3 Квартал  2020г
16    Компания     Ноябрь  2020г
17    Компания    Декабрь  2020г
0     Компания       Март  2022г
1     Компания  2 Квартал  2022г
4     Компания  3 Квартал  2022г
7     Компания  4 Квартал  2022г
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Решение без apply.
Сначала делаем булев массив, True - там где есть полный квартал. Меняем все названия месяцев в этих строках на номер квартала. Потом в выборке по булеву массиву удаляем дубликаты - будут удалены все повторы кварталов, а пустые строки заполнятся NaN'ами. Их дропаем.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Контрагенты': ['Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания', 'Компания'],
                   'Период': ['Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
                   'Год': ['2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2022г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г', '2020г']})

q = {'Январь': 1, 'Февраль': 1, 'Март': 1, 'Апрель': 2, 'Май': 2, 'Июнь': 2, 'Июль': 3, 'Август': 3, 'Сентябрь': 3, 'Октябрь': 4, 'Ноябрь': 4, 'Декабрь': 4}

kv = df.groupby([df['Период'].replace(q), 'Год'], as_index=False, sort=False)['Период'].transform('count').gt(2)
df.loc[kv, 'Период'] = df.loc[kv, 'Период'].replace(q).astype(str) + ' кв.'
df[kv] = df[kv].drop_duplicates(['Период', 'Год'])
df = df.dropna()
print(df)
```

```
   Контрагенты   Период    Год
0     Компания     Март  2022г
1     Компания    2 кв.  2022г
4     Компания    3 кв.  2022г
7     Компания    4 кв.  2022г
10    Компания     Март  2020г
11    Компания   Апрель  2020г
12    Компания     Июнь  2020г
13    Компания    3 кв.  2020г
16    Компания   Ноябрь  2020г
17    Компания  Декабрь  2020г
```